# Why does ontap change all cards

Tags: flutter, dart

I am still new to coding and still learning dart. I can't find a solution anywhere. please help. when I run my code, everything works fine but when i add multiple cards, when i tap one, they all change color and have a strikethrough. I am not sure where the problem is. Please can you help, here is my code:

```
@override

  bool _enabled = true;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('To-Do List'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      ),
      body: ListView(children: _getItems()),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => _displayDialog(context),
          tooltip: 'Add Item',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _addTodoItem(String title) {
    //Wrapping it inside a set state will notify
    // the app that the state has changed

    setState(() {
      _todoList.add(title);
    });
    _textFieldController.clear();
  }

  final Map<String, bool> _enabledMap = Map<String, bool>();

  Widget _buildTodoItem(String title) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 0.0),
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      ),
        child: InkWell(
        onTap: () => setState(() {
    item.isTapped = !item.isTapped;
    // _enabled = !_enabled;
    // _color = Colors.grey;
    }),
    child: Container(
          child: Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 75,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
            title,
              style: TextStyle(decoration:  _enabledMap[title] == true ?  TextDecoration.lineThrough, color : null: Colors.grey[700]),
            ),
            color: _color,
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  //Generate a single item widget
  _displayDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Add a task to your List'),
            content: TextField(
              controller: _textFieldController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter task here'),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: const Text('CANCEL'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: const Text('ADD'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  _addTodoItem(_textFieldController.text);
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
```

Comment: well, you need to add the enable value for every card separately.

Comment: How? i am not sure how to do that

Comment: create separate bool variables for every widget you are creating...

Comment: can i get the bool variables to create every time i create a new card

Comment: yeah you can if you have a list.

Comment: My code makes it that every time i click the add button it adds a new card but when i use the ontap it affects all the cards. is there a way to make it that it adds the bool variables every time I add a card

Answer (score 0):

Your `onTap` method updates the `_enabled` variable in setState.
That variable is used for **all** the containers in their TextStyle widget.

In order to select one item, I suggest creating a map that'll store your "enabled" logic, and the key should be a unique String (the title).

Something like below: (not tested)

```
final Map<String, bool> _enabledMap = Map<String, bool>();

enter code here
Widget _buildTodoItem(String title) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 0.0),
  child: Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
  ),
    child: InkWell(
    onTap: () => setState(() { if (_enabledMap[title] == null) {_enabledMap[title] = false;} _enabledMap[title] = !_enabledMap[title]; _color = Colors.grey;}),
      child: Container(
        width: 50,
        height: 75,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(decoration:  _enabledMap[title] == true ?  TextDecoration.lineThrough, color: Colors.grey[700] : null),
        ),
        color: _color,
      ),
    ),
  )
);
```

Comment: i get these two errors: A value of type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, bool>'.              A nullable expression can't be used as a condition.

Comment: @meltdown_ultra My bad, the map initialization was incorrect. Please try the updated version.

Comment: it now says that a nullable expression can't be used as an expression

Comment: @meltdown_ultra probably due to the condition in the TextStyle. Try again, V2 :)

Comment: it creates  5 new errors: A nullable expression can't be used as a condition70. ; Expected an identifier.78 ; Expected to find ':'.78 ; Expected to find ')'.78 ; Expected to find ')'.84

Comment: Shruti's answer is better than mine, take a look there :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Details {
  String title;
  bool isTapped;
  Details({this.title, this.isTapped});
}

class Testing2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Testing2State createState() => _Testing2State();
}

class _Testing2State extends State<Testing2> {
  @override
  bool _enabled = true;
  List<Details> _todoList = [];
  List<Widget> lists = [];
  TextEditingController _textFieldController = TextEditingController();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('To-Do List'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      ),
      body: _getItems(), //ListView(children: _getItems()),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => _displayDialog(context),
          tooltip: 'Add Item',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _getItems() {
    return Container(
      child:_todoList.length>0? ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _todoList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return _buildTodoItem(_todoList[index]);
        })
        :Center(child: Text("It's Empty", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),),

    );
  }

  void _addTodoItem(String title) {
    setState(() {
      _todoList.add(Details(isTapped: false, title: title));
    });
    _textFieldController.clear();
  }

  Widget _buildTodoItem(Details item) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 0.0),
        child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            ),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => setState(() {
                item.isTapped = !item.isTapped;
              }),
              child: Container(
                width: 50,
                height: 75,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  item.title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      decoration:
                          item.isTapped ? null : TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                      color: Colors.grey[700]),
                ),
                color: item.isTapped ? Colors.grey : null,
                // _color
              ),
            )));
  }

  //Generate a single item widget
  _displayDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Add a task to your List'),
            content: TextField(
              controller: _textFieldController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter task here'),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: const Text('CANCEL'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: const Text('ADD'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  _addTodoItem(_textFieldController.text);
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i dont want to output from a list, i would prefer if it worked as i added each card

Comment: If  I'm not getting wrong. you are trying to handle that you tap the specific card from the list and it change their background color with strikethrough then my answer does same thing.

Comment: yes, it does the same thing but it runs from a list

Comment: so you are not using list ? add some few more code.

Comment: No, im not running from a list.

Comment: I input all the information each time i create a card in the app

Comment: Hey you said, you added multiple cards means working with list! Now I'm not getting your issue. please add some more code. I'm still able to help you, if you want.

Comment: i have add some more code, if you need any more, please just let me know

Comment: Okay I updated my answer please try. it works like you wanted. and I used dynamic list widget named `ListView.Builder()`. it's very reliable when we trying to implementing dynamic lists widgets and you were doing same thing. and if this helped you  please marking my answer. Thank you :)